# Utilizing both inheritance and polymorphism to draw images?

Tags: java, image, inheritance, polymorphism, paint

I am trying so I can have three values in the parent class (img, LocX, LocY) that are supposed to be able to change depending on which child class they are in.

I want to have it so when I try to use the method to draw the player, it will draw the player. However I want to be able to use that same method to be able to draw the enemy when it is used to draw the enemy. I need to do it this way as I am required to use inheritance and polymorphism.

I am not getting any syntax errors, but I am getting errors when I try to run my game (it was working before I started to try to do it this way). Here is the code for where the parent and child classes are:

```
public abstract class Entity { //hold things such as player, and values realted to that specific entity (nice especially for organization purposes), both player and enemy the same health and speed, however they have different images that go along with them

    protected MazeModel model = new MazeModel();
    protected Image i = new Image();

    //both enemy and player have images, and have locations, so it was easy to get both inheritance and polymorphism in this one if they shared an abstract image, and set of coordinates

    abstract BufferedImage img(); //was looking at ways to extend a single BufferedImage to multiple classes for inheritance, I ended up finding out that they way to do it also covers polymorphism (originally did not have an idea for how to apply polymorphism)
    abstract int LocX();
    abstract int LocY();
    protected BufferedImage image; //they all have images, however they are different in each class
    //these are what is in common between player and enemy, these are currently not in use, however it is still inheritism
    protected int health = 100; //these two are not implemented yet, but are there to show inheritance
    protected int speed = 50;
}

class Player extends Entity{ //Inheritance
    BufferedImage img(){
        return i.getPlayer(); //img is the player's image in this case
    }

    int LocX(){
        return model.getPlayerX(); //gets the player's x
    }

    int LocY(){
        return model.getPlayerY(); //gets the player's y
    }

    private int playerHealth = health;
    private int playerSpeed = speed;
    //setters and getters to use the player's values
    public void setPlayerHealth(int playerHealth){
        this.playerHealth = playerHealth;
    }
    public int getPlayerHealth(){
        return playerHealth;
    }
    //  
    public Player(MazeModel model){ //constructor
        this.model = model;
    }
    private BufferedImage image = i.getPlayer();
    //for setting the player's initial starting point
    public void setPlayerStart(int x, int y){
        model.setPlayerX(x); //sets the starting x position of the player's image
        model.setPlayerY(y); //sets the starting y position of the player's image
        System.out.println("Your current coordinates are " + model.getPlayerX() + ", " + model.getPlayerY());
    }
    //for drawing the player
    public void paintImg(Entity e, Graphics g){ //polymorphism
        g.drawImage(e.img(), e.LocX(), e.LocY(), null);
    }

    public void playerPaint(Graphics g){
        g.drawImage(image, model.getPlayerX(), model.getPlayerY(), null); //creates the user
    }
}
//these next two I will possibly add later if I have the time
class Enemy extends Entity{
    BufferedImage img(){
        return i.getEnemy();
    }

    int LocX(){
        return model.getEnemyX(); //gets the player's x
    }

    int LocY(){
        return model.getEnemyY(); //gets the player's y
    }

    private int enemyHealth = health;
    private int enemySpeed = speed;
    private int enemyX = 400;
    private int enemyY = 50;
    private BufferedImage image = i.getEnemy();

    public void paintImg(Entity e, Graphics g){
        g.drawImage(e.img(), e.LocX(), e.LocY(), null);
    }

    public void paintEnemy(Graphics g){
        g.drawImage(image, model.getEnemyX(), model.getEnemyY(), null); //enemies location, fixed position for now
    }
}
```

Here is the code for the JPanel that does all of the drawing:

```
public class MazePanel extends JPanel {
    private Maze maze = new Maze(); //so I can paint the maze
    private MazeModel model;
    private Player p;
    private Enemy e = new Enemy();
    private Entity ent;

    public MazePanel(MazeModel model){ //constructor
        p = new Player(model);
        p.setPlayerStart(50, 50); //sets the player's starting coordinates
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500)); //map size
        setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY); //ground color
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        maze.paintMaze(g); //creates the walls
        e.paintImg(ent, g);
        p.paintImg(ent, g);
    }
}
```

I believe that I am close to getting this, but for some reason I can not figure out exactly what is going wrong. Again I want to be able to do it this way because I am required to use both inheritance, and polymorphism in some way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This in Player looks questionable:

```
//for drawing the player
public void paintImg(Entity e, Graphics g){ //polymorphism
    g.drawImage(e.img(), e.LocX(), e.LocY(), null);
}

public void playerPaint(Graphics g){
    g.drawImage(image, model.getPlayerX(), model.getPlayerY(), null); //creates the user
}
```

The first method, paintImg does not use require any state of the object nor does it change state, and could be static. I'm not sure why you comment it as polymorphic since polymorphic it most definitely is not.

In fact I'd merge the two methods above and would put them in the Entity class. To get polymorphism, you must inherit methods, and your Entity class has none. I'd create a method, paintImg, or better, `paintEntity, and have it use a Graphics parameter and its own state to paint iteself, and then have your other objects inherit this method and modify it if need be.

Comment: @Hoevercraft Full Of Eels Alright I will try what you are saying in a little bit. Is there a way to have both polymorphism and inheritance in what I am trying to do, am I close?

Comment: @user1234:  you can't have polymorphism **without** inheritance. Please re-read about these guys before sallying forth as understanding them better won't be wasted effort.

Comment: yeah I get that, but I was just wondering is there a way I could implement something like what I am trying to do where it would actually be able to paint(); ad repaint() the image in question as need be.

Comment: I am just wondering that if I do it the way that you are suggesting with the method above would it successfully do both polymorphism and inheritance, and actually work for both painting and repainting the enemy and player? I do get what you are saying to do.

Comment: @user1234: You can answer this yourself: 1) does what I suggest use inheritance and polymorphism? 2) can this method be used to paint and repaint with?

Comment: from what I can tell it seems that it would work correctly for what I am trying to do. I was just asking because I have never done something exactly like this before.

Comment: @user1234: best to try it and find out.

Comment: I will give a shot, and see if I can make it work. Otherwise I will let you know if I am having issues.